# What’s difference between UIKit Dynamics and UIKit Animation?

Tags: ios, uikit, core-animation, uikit-dynamics

What is the most essential difference between UIKit Dynamics and UIKit Animation at the animation level?

There is not a lot of information about UIKit Dynamic. I don't know much about it. I just know how to use it. I think this question is related to the hardware level?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If by UIKit Animation you mean Content Animations or Views Animation in the documentation it states their specific usage: [Animation and Haptics](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/animation_and_haptics)

- **UIKit Dynamics: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/animation_and_haptics/uikit_dynamics**

  > **UIKit Dynamics** 
  >   Apply physics-based animations to your views.
- **Views Animation**: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator

  > **UIViewPropertyAnimator** A class that animates changes to views and
  >   allows the dynamic modification of those animations.

In case by UIKit Animation you meant [Core Animations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore), maybe this answer can help you more to get an understanding. To sum up it says that the difference relies only in the APIs being more convenient as everything at the end uses Core Animations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38965402/3564632

Comment: thanks for the answer, I’ll check the link to understanding them.